# The correct way to get display rotation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make methods about the display rotation, I know that the following code `windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation` is deprecated from Java to Kotlin. My goal here is to recreate as recommended to me in [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/Display#getRotation()) website. I don't know if I done it correctly so that's why I am typing it here to be sure if I've done something wrong to edit it out or fixing it on the right order. Because I am really confused up at this point. Thank you in advance.

```
/**
* This will get the display ID as an Int to identify the rotation of the display, before that it casted the DisplayManager in order to get the services. Then returns to get the ID Int from the display.
*/
private fun getDisplay(displayId: Int): Display? {
        val displayManager: DisplayManager = baseContext.getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
        return displayManager.getDisplay(displayId)
    }

/**
* This is where we get the orientation as type Int, the return statement must be Int and it's not declared as null, it needs to be non-null.
*/
    fun getOrientation(): Int {
        val rotation = this.getOrientation()
        val orientation = when (getDisplay(rotation)!!.rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_0 -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            Surface.ROTATION_180 -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT
            Surface.ROTATION_270 -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE
            Surface.ROTATION_90 -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            else -> Log.e("Display", "Orientation not connected.")
        }
        return orientation
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for the orientation of the device wether on `PORTRAIT` or `LANDSCAPE` mode you can use this following code for more simplicity

```
private fun isPortrait(): Boolean {
    val config: Configuration = resources.configuration
    return config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
}
```

Comment: Ok, looks really simple to me, but what about the Reverse Portrait and Landscape, since that doesn't have in the ```Configuration``` ?

Comment: @GeorgiTasev in the google documentation says `Overall orientation of the screen. May be one of ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.` so when you look for the orientation of the reverse portrait it will be the same as portrait in layout and design